# I want to set minimum app window size . I don't want to resize window less than that minimum value but want to resize app window

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

I want to lock minimum size of window with minimumWidth 1080 and minimumHeight 700

```
#if WINDOWS
  
        var mauiWindow = handler.VirtualView;
        var nativeWindow = handler.PlatformView;
        nativeWindow.Activate();
        IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
        WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
        AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
        
        var presenter = appWindow.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter;
        if(width<WindowWidth || height<WindowHeight)
        {
             appWindow.Resize(new SizeInt32(WindowWidth,WindowHeight));
        }
```

#endif
this code is working fine for launching app window.
I don't want to set IsResizable= false because I want to resize my application greater than WindowHeightand minimumWidth.

Comment: Have you checked this discussion here  [How to specify a fixed size for the application window](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/2370)?